# How to test dynamic imports (then and catch) with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, dynamic-import

So I have been struggling with how to test dynamic imports generally and in this case, especially in jest, I have been reading a lot on the internet but did not find anything concrete, so I thought about bringing the question up to centralize a decent solution.

I have the following methods inside of a class

```
class MyClass {
   successMethod() {  ...  }

   errorMethod() { ... }

    myMethod() {
        return import('./myFile.js')
           .then(() => this.successMethod())
           .catch(() => this.errorMethod());
    }
}
```

**My question is:**

How do you mock both Success and Failing promise cases for this dynamic import using Jest to make sure each method (`successMethod` and `errorMethod`) are called when resolving or failing respectively?.

I found `jest.doMock` helps for mocking the resolved case but did not find a way to make the dynamic import fail by mocking it so the `catch` case is uncovered.

**Note:** this is not a react application, this is a Vanilla JS project.

Comment: what about `jest.mock('./myFile.js', () => Promise.reject(new Error('Forcing async import error')));`?

Comment: @DipenShah This will result in successful import with `default` export being promise object.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes and that should help you test fail scenario, right? Could you please share codesandbox/stablitz project, is should work afaik.

Comment: @DipenShah jest.mock return is treated as CommonJS export which is translated to ESM `default` export. It will trigger `then` callback and not `catch`, because `import` returns a promise of ES module export object, which in this case is `{ default: Promise.reject(...) }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prototype methods can be spied or mocked on either `MyClass.prototype` or class instance. Module mocks and spy functions should be restored for each test in order for them to not affect each other.

```
let myClass;
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
  myClass = new MyClass();
  jest.spyOn(myClass, 'successMethod');
  jest.spyOn(myClass, 'errorMethod');
});
```

`jest.doMock` requires to import all affected modules after it was called. In order for dynamic `import` to result in rejected promise, `myFile` module should throw an error when evaluated. Since dynamic `import` returns a promise, tests should be asynchronous.

```
it('...', async () => {
  jest.mock('./myFile.js', () => 'value');
  await expect(myClass.myMethod()).resolves.toEqual(/* return value from successMethod */);
  expect(myClass.successMethod).toBeCalled();
  expect(myClass.errorMethod).not.toBeCalled();
});

it('...', async () => {
  jest.mock('./myFile.js', () => { throw new Error() });
  await expect(myClass.myMethod()).rejects.toThrow(/* error message from errorMethod */);
  expect(myClass.successMethod).not.toBeCalled();
  expect(myClass.errorMethod).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: I was already doing this but it wasn't working, now I found out that it is because I wasn't using `jest.resetModules();` and `jest.restoreAllMocks();` just to accept the answer could you change the error case to `.rejects` instead of `.resolves`.

Comment: It should be `resolves` instead of `rejects` because of `catch` - unless it's errorMethod that causes a rejection.

Comment: Yes in my case the errot method causes a rejection.

Comment: You can remove the comment about the discrepancies of the_ in the methods, I fixed it to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});
beforeAll(() => {
  MyClass.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      successMethod: () => {
        console.log("succees");
      },
      errorMethod: () => {
        console.log("error");
      }
    };
  });
});

test("should fail", () => {
  jest.doMock("./myFile.js", () => {
    return jest.fn(() => {
      throw new Error("Parameter is not a number!");
    });
  });
  const kls = MyClass();
  kls.myMethod();
  expect(kls.errorMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(kls.successMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
});
test("should pass", () => {
  jest.doMock("./myFile.js", () => {
    return jest.fn(() => 1);
  });
  const kls = MyClass();
  kls.myMethod();
  expect(kls.errorMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  expect(kls.successMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: The chosen approach is right but there are several problems here. MyClass is not a spy and cannot be mocked. Mocked implementation lacks original myMethod and there's nothing to test. myMethod is asynchronous and needs asynchronous tests.